# Collada terrain missig texture

Tags: texturing, import, collada

I really hope that someone has the time to help out a complete newb regarding blender.

I hava a collada terrain thats been exported from QGIS. When exporting the terrain i get two files with the same name; one .dae (collada model) and one .png (texture).

I can import the collada file inte blender fine, but i really cant wrap my head around the texture file. When I export it i have a nice texturized terrain 3D modell (arial photo). In blender I get the bland collada file without any texture. I've tried looking at few dozen tutorials and forums, tried with materials, textures and shrinkwrap (in blender) but without any better results than getting the collade texturized with hundreds of miniversions of my picture.

Can anybody please explain how to get my arial photo on my terrain? Or at least point me in the right direction.

I would be extremely greatful since I'm starting to feel like a complete tech idiot (and I'm a GIS engineer :)

I've tried exporting to wawvefront and stl and importing in blender with the same results.